# Google Docs script editor trying to autogenerate an email from an autogenerated document

Tags: google-apps-script, editor, documentation, google-docs

Everything I've found about this topic includes having a google sheet populate a google doc which then sends an email.  I personally have pasted some code I found around the web into script editor of a doc.  Now, upon opening a doc, the user is prompted to answer question boxes.  the answers autopopulate a new document that is created.  The script then calls for an email to be sent out.

So far, I have the prompts correct, the new document is created, with the correctly filled-in information from the prompt boxes.  I have also gotten it to send an email to 1 address, which is all it is supposed to do.  The subject line of the email is also correct.  The problem is I want the new Google document that is created in the script to be the body of the email, and I just cannot figure out how to make that happen.

This is the code I have in script editor.  I have tried numerous things in the last line to make the body of the new document populate the email body, with no luck.  Can someone tell me the programming language for how to make this work please?

```
    function myFunction() {
      // Display a dialog box for each field you need information for.

      var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
      //var response = ui.prompt('Enter Name', 'Enter sales person's name', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
      var shiftResponse = ui.prompt('Enter shift, i.e. 7-3 or 3-11');
      var peersResponse = ui.prompt('Enter peers on shift');
      var participantsResponse = ui.prompt('Enter names of face to face encounters');
      var phonelogResponse = ui.prompt('Enter names of people we called on phone log');
      var filescreatedResponse = ui.prompt('Enter names of people we created files for');
      var notesResponse = ui.prompt('Enter any notes about shift');
      var cleanResponse = ui.prompt('Was Crisis Center Cleaned? Enter yes or no');
      var authorResponse = ui.prompt('Enter your name');
      var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "MM/dd/yyyy");

      //Make a copy of the template file
      var documentId = DriveApp.getFileById('1lXTJPvwlJrXkRJ807daFsFbfaiC_wl7EAQ4giixLeEc').makeCopy().getId();

      //Rename the copied file
      DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).setName(date + " " + shiftResponse.getResponseText() + ' Shift Report');  

      //Get the document body as a variable
      var body = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getBody();

      //Insert the entries into the document
      body.replaceText('##date##', date);
      body.replaceText('##shift##', shiftResponse.getResponseText());
      body.replaceText('##peers##', peersResponse.getResponseText());
      body.replaceText('##participants##', participantsResponse.getResponseText()); 
      body.replaceText('##phonelog##', phonelogResponse.getResponseText());
      body.replaceText('##filescreated##', filescreatedResponse.getResponseText());  
      body.replaceText('##notes##', notesResponse.getResponseText());
      body.replaceText('##clean##', cleanResponse.getResponseText());
      body.replaceText('##author##', authorResponse.getResponseText());  

      MailApp.sendEmail("jason.chrystal@voicesofhopececilmd.org", "Shift Report", body);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As it reads in the documentation:

The replaceText methods expects a regex pattern value as the first parameter:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#replacetextsearchpattern,-replacement

Also the last parameter of the MailApp.sendMail parameter expects a string and you are giving it a body class object.

Change your first parameter to a correct matching regex pattern and your code will work just fine.

```
body.replaceText(/^##date##$/, date);
body.replaceText(/^##shift##$/, shiftResponse.getResponseText());
body.replaceText(/^##peers##$/, peersResponse.getResponseText());
etc...
```

-- regex not tested.

If you are not comfortable with regular expressions you can use body.setText() as an alternative like so:

```
var oldBodyText = body.getText();
body = body.setText(oldBodyText.replace('##date##', date));

oldBodyText = body.getText();
body = body.setText(oldBodyText.replace('##shift##', shiftResponse.getResponseText()));

oldBodyText = body.getText();
body = body.setText(oldBodyText.replace('##peers##', peersResponse.getResponseText()));

etc...

// And then the last lines:
var newBody = body.getText();
MailApp.sendEmail("jason.chrystal@voicesofhopececilmd.org", "Shift Report", newBody);
```

Comment: And that won't mess up the part that already works?  And will make the email body content to be the entire new document?  I don't want to only send the prompt answers.

Comment: So I just tried that and the email that is generated has a body that just reads "DocumentBody Section"

Comment: I suspect you did not notice that the first paramater of replaceText needs to be a regex.

Comment: So, I tried that and the body of the email now reads "DocumentBodySection"

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: So truly you are speaking another language to me with the "regex pattern values" and such.  I am not fluent in any of this.  I tried copying and pasting your suggested version with the

Comment: var oldBodyText etc and doing that for all the lines.

Comment: Ok, for debugging, just try: body.setText('This is some sample text'); and see if at least that works. So we can determine where the problem occurs.

Comment: So, the newly generated document just says "This is some sample text," without any of the other parts, even though I did not change any code, only added that code.  Yet the email just read "undefined"

Comment: Ok so we got to the real problem here. The SendMail method last parameter needs to be of type string. Il change the answer again....

Comment: hold on, that might be my fault, let me try that again.

Comment: Okay, document says "This is some sample text" and email says "DocumentBodySection"

Comment: Ok, now i got it: last parameter needed to be string. Check last answer update. This will work now ^^

Comment: You are an incredible human being.  IT WORKED!  It didn't quite carry over the format of the text from the original document, for example, the new document doesn't have underlined text or a centered title, but at this point I'm thrilled and it is okay.

Comment: Haha, it took some comments. I am glad I was able to help! xD